# Error in using variables in SQL statement in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I have the following Python code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()


a = "C6DE6778-5956-48D4-BED6-5A2A37BBB123"
SQLCommand = ("""SELECT *
                 FROM Table
                 WHERE  Table.ENUM = ?
              """, a)

results = cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
```

The following error is returned:

```
TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of tuple instance
```

Comment: What library are you using to connect to your database? It may not support Prepared Statements like that.

Comment: @Darnell Martin pypyodbc

Comment: I think it should work : ``` a = "C6DE6778-5956-48D4-BED6-5A2A37BBB123"
sql = "SELECT *
                 FROM Table
                 WHERE  Table.ENUM = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, a) ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLCommand` is a tuple in your case. `.execute()` expects sql statement as the first argument. To rectify the error, you can  do something like this :

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
a = "C6DE6778-5956-48D4-BED6-5A2A37BBB123"
SQLCommand = """SELECT *
                 FROM Table
                 WHERE  Table.ENUM = '%s'
              """ % a
results = cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
```

Alternatively, you can format you SQL statement string like this :

```
SQLCommand = """SELECT *
                     FROM Table
                     WHERE  Table.ENUM = '{}'
                  """.format(a)
```

---

Or you can pass `a` as an optional parameter to `.execute()` like this :

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
a = "C6DE6778-5956-48D4-BED6-5A2A37BBB123"
SQLCommand = """SELECT *
                FROM Table
                WHERE  Table.ENUM = ?
            """
print(SQLCommand, a)
```

You can refer to [the documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#methods) for more understanding on this.

Answer (score 3):

The way you constructed the sqlcommand is incorrect. Pass the parameter when you `execute`.

```
a = "C6DE6778-5956-48D4-BED6-5A2A37BBB123"
SQLCommand = """SELECT *
                 FROM Table
                 WHERE  Table.ENUM = ?
              """

results = cursor.execute(SQLCommand,(a,))
```